# Silverlight databind int to lookless control not working

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I am working a very simple lookless control, and I can't seem to get one of the template bindings to work.  In the control I have two Dependency Properties, the one that is a string works, and the one that is an int does not.

The csharp code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ControlDemo
{
    public class TextControlLookless : Control
    {
        #region Title

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ChartTitle", typeof(string), typeof(TextControlLookless),
            null);


        public String ChartTitle
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ChartTitleProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ChartTitleProperty, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Value

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ChartValue", typeof(int), typeof(TextControlLookless),
            null);


        public int ChartValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ChartValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ChartValueProperty, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ctor

        public TextControlLookless()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextControlLookless);
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And the xaml for the control looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlDemo">

<Style TargetType="local:TextControlLookless">
    <Setter Property="ChartTitle" Value="Set Title" />
    <Setter Property="ChartValue" Value="1" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TextControlLookless">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ChartTitle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ChartValue}" Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I put this on a page, I can see the ChartTitle (either Set Title, or whatever I set it to), but the ChartValue never shows up.  If I change its type to a string, it does show up, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `TemplateBinding` is a far more primitive operation than `Binding`.  `Binding` is an actual class and includes some helpful features including the implicit conversion of strings back and forth between other data types.

`TemplateBinding` is purely a markup instruction and crucially in your case does not do type conversion for you.  Hence the dependency property being bound to a `Text` property of a `TextBlock` must be a string.

You have two choices:-

One choice is instead using TemplateBinding give the `TextBlock` a name and assign its `Text` in the `ChartValue` property changed call back:-

```
    #region Value

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChartValue", typeof(int), typeof(TextControlLookless),
        new PropertyMetadata(0, OnChartValuePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnChartValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextControlLookless source = d as TextControlLookless;
        source.Refresh();
    }


    public int ChartValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ChartValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChartValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private TextBlock txtChartValue { get; set; }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        txtChartValue = GetTemplateChild("txtChartValue") as TextBlock;
        Refresh();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        if (txtChartValue != null)
        {
            txtChartValue.Text = ChartValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

where the xaml looks like:-

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtChartValue" Grid.Row="1" />
```

The other choice is to create a private dependency property for the value with type of string:-

```
        #region Value

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ChartValue", typeof(int), typeof(TextControlLookless),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, OnChartValuePropertyChanged));

        private static void OnChartValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            d.SetValue(ChartValueStrProperty, e.NewValue.ToString());
        }

        private static readonly DependencyProperty ChartValueStrProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ChartValueStr", typeof(string), typeof(TextControlLookless),
            new PropertyMetadata("0"));

        public int ChartValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ChartValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ChartValueProperty, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

where the xaml looks like:-

```
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ChartValueStr}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Note that the `ChartValueStrProperty` is private and I haven't bothered creating a standard .NET property to cover it.  `TemplateBinding` actually takes the property name you assign suffixes is with "Property" then looks for a static field on the target type.

Both approaches have their strengths and weaknesses.  The first approach is the more common pattern but takes a little more code and is less flexiable (the control displaying the value must be a TextBlock).  The second is more flexiable and uses less code but is somewhat unorthodox.

Comment: I like how the second one works, it seems to flow better in my head.